# Phonegap access user location Info.plist

Tags: location, phonegap, sharing, info.plist

I have an app that uses the user's location to find landmarks they are near. After submitting my Phonegap app to the iOS store, it is getting rejected for the following reason:

"We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access their location but does not clarify the use of the location in the applicable purpose string. Please revise the relevant purpose string in your app’s Info.plist file to specify why the app is requesting access to the user's location. You can modify your app's Info.plist file using the property list editor in Xcode."

I thought I had addressed this issue by adding the following to my config.xml file:

```
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>The user's location is used to find the distance they are from certain landmarks.</string>
</edit-config>
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.myapp" version="1.0.10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26"/>
    <description>
        A blank PhoneGap app.
    </description>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="2.4.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.4.0" />
    <edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>The user's location is used to find the distance they are from landmarks.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <icon src="images/icon.png" />
    <icon height="40" platform="ios" src="images/icon40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="76" platform="ios" src="images/icon76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="120" platform="ios" src="images/icon120.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="152" platform="ios" src="images/icon152.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="1024" platform="ios" src="images/icon1024.png" width="1024" />
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

However, it is still getting rejected for this reason. How could I modify the config.xml or anything else to not get rejected for this reason on the iOS store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed this part:

```
<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
        <string>The user's location is used to find the distance they are from certain landmarks.</string>
</edit-config>
```

and added this part:

```
<plugin name="cordova-custom-config" version="*"/>
<config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist"> <string>Your location is used to find how far you are from landmarks.</string> </config-file>
<config-file overwrite="true" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist"> <string>Your location is used to find how far you are from landmarks.</string> </config-file>
```

Now it's working as expected.